# Bundle Install Permission Denied Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

I have just cloned a project to start playing around with. Getting the error below. I have exhausted the other answers on here as none of them seemed to cure the problem. I am only just getting started with web dev so bare with with me. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

I have been through the bundler troubleshooting and tried the fixes they suggest without any joy...

```
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:ytutorial patrickwalsh$ bundle install
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting       documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/kgio-2.7.4 (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo bundle install
```

You gem is install in System. Change path in bash file. And it will solve the issues. You simply enter,

```
bundle install.
```

Comment: Thanks @Amritdeep Dhungana. What should I change in my .bashrc file?

Currently it looks like this:


    PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]⚡\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;33m\]${PWD##*/}\[\e[m\] '

    export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

    [[ -s "/home/patricks-mbp/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source      "/home/patricks-mbp/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

    export #PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

    ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting'

Comment: Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo bundle install`. Looks like issue with permissions on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to write on /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/kgio-2.7.4 directory.

The error logs states that it tries to create a dir (with mkdir) and the permission is denied!

Can you do # bundle install has root?